# SQL Server - Rollback on Failed Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Does a failed trigger cause a rollback in the subscriber AND the distributor?  Or only the subscriber?

Comment: All transactions are in the database - what do you mean by subscriber or distributor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does rollback both subscriber and distributor.

Comment: @DannyAckerman if this is the answer you were after then please mark is as the accepted answer